# Node JS Bluebird nested loops promise

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird in NodeJS. I want to do a nested loop. Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (i !== j) {
            // do some stuff
        }
   }
}
```

How can I promisify this loop with bluebird?

I see some similar question here
[How to use promise bluebird in nested for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335542/how-to-use-promise-bluebird-in-nested-for-loop)
or here
[in node.js, how to use bluebird promise with a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104253/in-node-js-how-to-use-bluebird-promise-with-a-for-loop)

But that does not clarify my doubt. I would like some explanation besides the code, since I do not really understand what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you're using Node, you have coroutines, use them:

```
function myWork = Promise.coroutine(function*() {
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
       if (i !== j) {
           // do some stuff
           // this can be async calls, for example
           yield thisReturnsAPromise(i, j); // call some async function
       }
     }
  }
});
```

To handle errors you can use regular `try/catch`. To call it you do `doWork()` with also returns a promise which you can `then` or `catch`.

The issue is that until ES2015 and generators, you had [issues with returning async values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and using them with regular flow control structures. In old Node, you'd have to use `Promise.each` on the array nested in a `Promise.each` returned and return the inner promise in that:

```
Promise.each(array, function(i) {
    return Promise.each(array, function(j) {
        return thisReturnAPromise(i, j); 
    });
});
```

Coroutines simplify this and `yield` back control to the promise pump that takes care of that.